# Chromium (or Firefox) extension for right clicking and downloading media

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, download, firefox-addon, right-click

I am trying to  implement this in a chromium extension:

```
On start of browser:
  Create an event listener for right click events on the document
  When a right click event is triggered:
    Prevent the default context menu from appearing
    Check if the target element of the right click event is of type "video", "audio" or "image"
    If the target element is of type "video", "audio" or "image":
      Get the URL of the media file
      Check if the media file is already present in the default download destination
      If the media file is not present in the default download destination:
        Start a download with the URL and the original file name
    Else:
      Do nothing
```

I tried various permutations and combinations of this code. This is the latest what I have for background.js

```
document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let media = event.target;
  let url = media.src;
  let ext = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("."));
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", url, true);
  xhr.responseType = "blob";
  xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      let blob = xhr.response;
      let filename = media.currentSrc.split("/").pop();
      let link = document.createElement("a");
      link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      link.download = filename;
      link.click();
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
}, false);
```

This is my manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Media Saver",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Saves media files with the correct extension.",
  "permissions": [
    "contextMenus",
    "storage",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

Chromium still shows the context menu, and still does not download any media. My goals are this:

1. When I right click, no menu should be visible. The only action should be that the media file gets downloaded.
2. Make it automatically download the media silently in the default destination, rather than prompting the user for destination.
3. The name of the media must be the original name.
4. So not download the file if the file is already present in the destination.

Any help would be much appreciated. The extension can be made to work either in Chromium, or Firefox.

Comment: The background.js you posted doesn't have context menu registration handling. You posted the wrong background.js and need to fix it.

Comment: Questions should focus on a specific problem.  Providing a list of requirements and asking how to implement an entire feature is much too broad.

Comment: The `contextmenu` event won't work. You need to use browser.contextMenus or browser.menus API. To download the links you can use browser.downloads API instead of your current code. See the documentation for more info and examples.

Comment: @wOxxOm The code is for chromium. For Firefox I tried "browser.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener". It did not work. I am new to this. Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: @NorioYamamoto How should I do it? I am new to this. I think that there is only one background.js, in each extension. Should I use multiple javascript files for this?

Comment: @Yogi This is not a feature list. This is a single method. It somehow does not register with either of the browsers. If you can suggest better wording, please provide. I provided the entire JavaScript method and its pseudocode, that is all.

Comment: @NorioYamamoto Thanks. I shall look into it later, when I have time. I gave up on this idea, as it seems to be something bigger than what a beginner can do, and I got busy.